# Routing Error No route matches [GET] "/salesforce/MerchandiseCs"

Tags: ruby, salesforce

i am trying to make a connection with salesforce
I use abanta when i try to open the web page
this what i have

> Routing Error
>
> No route matches [GET] "/salesforce/MerchandiseCs"
>
> Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.

I don't understand what this
any help please

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and write: "rake routes".
You will see the available routes. The error is because "/salesforce/MerchandiseCs" is not in the list.

Comment: thanks but when I Use rake routs it give me this result
salesforce_merchandise__cs GET    /salesforce/merchandise__cs(.:format)          salesforce/merchandise__cs#index

so I go for this url http://localhost:3000/salesforce/merchandise__cs

but it give me this result 

Routing Error

uninitialized constant Salesforce::MerchandiseCsController

Comment: Check the views of merchandise controller you would be using something in the view that you are not defining in the controller.